# Deserialize JSON when structure known but not the keys

Tags: json, rust

I am trying to deserialize some crypto exchange JSON. The structure of the JSON is predictable but the keys are not. Each time the server adds a new currency it becomes a new key. For example, it looks something like this:

```
{
  "timestamp":"1562405",
  "username":"1234",
  "BTC":
    {"available":"0.00","orders":"0.00000000"},
  "BCH":
    {"available":"0.0000000","orders":"0.00000000"},
  ..

  ..

  "GUSD":
    {"available":"0.00","orders":"0.00"}
}
```

I tried the usual approach of defining a struct to deserialize into but every time there is a new currency my program will have an error.

I thought I would just read it all into a `Value` and then just iterate over it manually to put it all into a struct.

```
let balance_data: Value = serde_json::from_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&body)).unwrap();
println!("balance_data: {:?}", balance__data);

for element in balance_data.iter() {
    //push into a proper map...
}
```

But I can't:

```
no method named `iter` found for type `serde_json::Value`.
```

I thought I would put it into a `Vec<Value>` but this causes a panic:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called ``Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("invalid type: map, expected a sequence", line: 1, column: 0)'`
```

I also experimented with reading it into a `HashMap` but couldn't quite seem to crack it.

It would be amazing if we could do something like:

```
let balance_data: RecvBalance = serde_json::from_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&body)).unwrap();

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct RecvBalance {
    timestamp: String,
    username: String,
    HashMap<String, RecvBalanceData>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct RecvBalanceData {
    available: String,
    orders: String,
}
```

Has anyone dealt with this situation? I need a struct with the balance data in it that I can lookup later in my program.

Comment: your question could be better with a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html#capture-additional-fields) has a related example. You need to put the `HashMap` and use `flatten` attribute:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct RecvBalance {
    timestamp: String,
    username: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    moneys: HashMap<String, RecvBalanceData>,
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I looked at the flatten and didn't understand its usefulness!